# How do i complete this question with 2-dimensional array in java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, shuffle

Hey guys, im working through the Introduction to Programming in Java book and one of the exercises is this:

> **Empirical shuffle check**. Run
>   computational experiments to check
>   that our shuffling code works as
>   advertised. Write a program
>   ShuffleTest that takes command-line
>   arguments M and N, does N shuffles of
>   an array of size M that is initialized
>   with a[i] = i before each shuffle, and
>   prints an M-by-M table such that row i
>   gives the number of times i wound up
>   in position j for all j. All entries
>   in the array should be close to N/M.

Now, this code just outputs a block of zeros...

```
public class ShuffleTest2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int M = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int N = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); 
    int [] deck = new int [M];

    for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
      deck [i] = i;

    int [][] a = new int [M][M];

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
        a[i][j] = 0 ;

        for(int n = 0; n < N; n++) {
          int r = i + (int)(Math.random() * (M-i));
          int t = deck[r];
          deck[r] = deck[i];
          deck[i] = t;

          for (int b = 0; b < N; b++)
          {
            for (int c = 0; c < M; c++)
              System.out.print(" " + a[b][c]);
            System.out.println();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What am i doing wrong? :(

Thanks

Comment: The only thing you put in `a` is `0`: `a[i][j] = 0 ;`

Comment: Maybe you didn't get the meaning of the subject, you can get the sample code here: https://github.com/paulogpafilho/algorithmsfourthedition/blob/master/src/algorithms/fourth/edition/fundamentals/ShuffleTest.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a is like a history? As you are now it is always filled with zeroes just like you initialized, you never assign to it!  After the "shuffling" for loop you need to set

```
A[i][POSITION] = CARD_VALUE
```

Meaning that after i-th shuffle, card CARD_VALUE is in position POSITION.  I don't want to give you all the specifics, but it will take another for loop, and the nested for-loop for printing needs to be independent of any other loop, occuring when everything else is done.

Looks like you have a few things concerning the for-loops that you need to look over carefully.  Trace the program flow manually or with a debugger and you'll notice that some of those braces and code blocks need to be moved.

--TRY THIS--

```
public class ShuffleTest2 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int M = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int N = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); 
    int [] deck = new int [M];

    int [][] a = new int [M][M]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {  //initialize a to all zeroes
      for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
        a[i][j] = 0 ; 
      }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)   //puts the deck in order, shuffles it, and records. N times
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)  //order the deck
          deck[j] = j;

        for(int j = 0; j < M; j++) {       //shuffle the deck (same as yours except counter name)
          int r = j + (int)(Math.random() * (M-j));
          int t = deck[r];
          deck[r] = deck[j];
          deck[j] = t;
        }

       for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)   //record status of this deck as described
       {
           int card_at_j = deck[j];  //value of card in position j
           a[card_at_j][j]++;        //tally that card_at_j occured in position j
       }
    }  //big loop ended

    for (int b = 0; b < M; b++)  //print loop.  a is MxM, so limit of N was wrong.
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < M; c++)
        {
           System.out.print(" " + a[b][c]);
           System.out.println();
        }
    }  //print loop ended
  }  //main() ended
 } //class ended
```

Comment: ok thanks for your help, i've taken the printing for loop outside now. I'm struggling to come up with an implementation to your solution, i feel like i've hit a wall... :(

Comment: it looks like you have some individual pieces that are good, but they are sometimes in the wrong order.  i'll give you some more direction in an edit

Comment: i feel like i might have given you too much and you would've got there if you just tried to pseudo-code it.  do you understand why things were happening in the wrong order and whats different now?

Comment: thank you so much for your time! i had been trying to work through pseudocode but for some reason this had totally stumped me! i see that it was being initialized in the wrong place, and that i had too many nested for loops, but i couldnt see how to rectify it! i was very close to the card_at_j bit, but then like you pointed out i had things in the wrong place etc so i wasnt really getting anyway! one thing i did change, as it was only outputting 1 number per line, was to place the <code>System.out.println();</code> outside of that last nested loop. it now shows as a block. is this the answer?

Comment: i.e. answer to the whole question, i think ive confused myself beyond recognition now, like repeating words until they lose all meaning... :S

Comment: yes that was a good switch, you should see a square of numbers now correct?  you might want to put a space in between for clarity, but so long as the numbers seem to correspond to the expected value (N/M) then it seems like you're good.  i haven't run the program, so you tell me

Comment: yeh they seem good, thanks very much! altho i do get a few wild ones in there sometime, guess thats just the accuracy of the shuffle...

Comment: honestly i didnt analyze your shuffle algorithm at all, figured thats what the simulation was for.  in short: it starts at the top of the deck and swaps each card with a randomly chosen one below it.  not physically realistic, but it seems viable - though i wouldnt be confident of its accuracy without a decent analysis or (in our case) simulation.

Comment: @jon_darkstar I don't think you need to explicitly initialize with the array 0's since int is a primitive type, the array is actually already filled with 0 at the instanciation time.